# Accessing SharePoint 2010 (using TMG/NTLM auth) via CSOM using C#

Tags: development, csom, 401

I can't seem to get past a 401 unauthorized error when using C# to access SP2010 CSOM. The auth of SP2010 is using TMG/NTLM.

I have tried [this](http://usingnat.net/sharepoint/2011/2/23/how-to-programmatically-authenticate-to-uag-protected-sharep.html) blog, but still getting 401. Anyone have luck with this kind of setup?